# Is a function analytic iff it has antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Fundamental theorem of line integral states that for any function $f$ that has an antiderivative $F$, integrating $f$ from point $a$ to point $b$ yields $F(b) -
 F(a)$, which would imply integration over a closed path yields $0$; However, Cauchy theorem requires the function to be analytic to guarantee $0$ on closed path integration. So does this mean any function that has primitive function $F$ will automatically be analytic and vice versa?

Comment: But if  by primitive of $f$ you mean there is an $F$ with$F'=f$, then $F$ itself is differentiable and therefore analytic -- and then so is $f$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Morera's theorem?

Comment: @gary Thank you for the answer. But what about the reverse? If f is analytic do we always have antiderivative such that $F'=f$?

Comment: @Daniel Li. Yes, if the domain is simply-connected.

Comment: @gary Can you walk me through your reasoning a bit on this? or on what  theorems is the conclusion based on? thank you!

Comment: @Daniel Li, this is part of Cauchy's Integral Theorem. The argument is constructive, i.e., it provides a formula for the antiderivative. And , BTw, this is largely how homology came about, in order to address these issues of the existence of antiderivatives. Let me see if I can come up with a good way of showing this.

Comment: @DanielLi: Please see the "Sufficiency" part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative_(complex_analysis) , near the bottom, and let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $f$ is analytic and defined in a simply-connected domain $D$, it will have an analytic antiderivative given by $ F(z)=\int_{\gamma_z}f(z)dz$ , where $\gamma$ is any curve living in $D$, i.e., $\frac {d}{dz}F(z):=\int_{\gamma_z}f(t)dt=f(z)$. See, e.g.:http://planetmath.org/antiderivativeofcomplexfunction

Comment: note, not necessarily true if the domain is not simply connected, for example 1/z on all C

Answer (score 0):

Because the derivative of a holomorphic function is itself holomorphic, any function that admits a primitive is holomorphic. However, the function $z\in \mathbb C\smallsetminus 0 \longmapsto z^{-1}\in \mathbb C$ admits no primitive on all its domain, because it winds once around the origin, and any function that admits a primitive must wind zero times around it.