# Evaluate $\int_{-i}^{i}|z| d z$ along different contours.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate $\int_{-i}^{i}|z| d z$ along different contours. Does $|z|$ have an antiderivative?

**Progress:**

If we say $z = x + iy$, then $f(z) = |z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + i*0$, so Cauchy-Riemann equations only satisfied at origin and it is not analytic. Therefore, we cannot apply Cauchy Theorem.

If we say $z = r*e^{i\theta}$, then $|z| = r$ and it looks like for each contour, we will get different result.

I don't know how to proceed after that.

Comment: If $|z|$ had an antiderivative, then the integral would be path independent, wouldn't it?

Comment: Depends on some circumstances for $|z|$.

Comment: @Kolja As it is not analytic, therefore it has no antiderivative (based on this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372566/is-a-function-analytic-iff-it-has-antiderivative). But, how can I get integration values along different contours?

Comment: It is contour independent, so just plug in some different paths and evaluate the integral? For example a straight line from $-i$ to $i$, and a circular path from $-i$ to $i$ where the circle is centered in $0$;.

Comment: I believe that you are not asked to give a closed form value of the integral for each contour, but simply to give the value of the integral along different contours (where the values of the integral are different), and show that $|z|$ does not have an antiderivative as a consequence.

Comment: got it. Thank you, so showing |z| is not analytic is enough I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically showing that $|z|$ is not analytic is enough to say that it has no antiderivative ([Is a function analytic iff it has antiderivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372566/is-a-function-analytic-iff-it-has-antiderivative)).

And we can simply take 2 contours: $C_1 = \{|Im z|<1 | Re z = 0 \}$ and $C_2 = \{|z|=1 | Arg z \in (-\pi, \pi) \}$ to get different results.